# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm updating one of our apps from rc4 to angular2.0.0 and I'm getting a template parse error at run time.  Here is my view template:

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" class="col-xs-3 quick-link">
    <a [routerLink]="['/Tile', widget.WidgetRoute.Feature, widget.WidgetRoute.SubFeature]">
        <div class="tile-icon">
            <span [className]="widget.IconCssClass"></span>
            <span *ngIf="widget.BadgeNumber > 0" class="badge">{{widget.BadgeNumber}}</span>
        </div>
        <h4>{{widget.Text}}</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the error is on the routerlink.  Here's the error:

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("

    <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" class="col-xs-3 quick-link">
        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/Tile', widget.WidgetRoute.Feature, widget.WidgetRoute.SubFeature]">
            <di"): LdrComponent@4:19
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("tile-icon">
                <span [className]="widget.IconCssClass"></span>
                <span [ERROR ->]*ngIf="widget.BadgeNumber > 0" class="badge">{{widget.BadgeNumber}}</span>
            </div>
     "): LdrComponent@7:22
```

The routerLink doesn't seem malformed to me... What did I do wrong?

Comment: Angular 2 version which you are using ?

Comment: Angular 2.0.0 the first release version

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to add `RouterModule` to your `NgModule` component. In the RC this was added to the `@Component({directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]})`, however, this is now moved into `@NgModule({ imports: [RouterModule]})`.

When you define your routes, one of the components that you will import will be the `RouterModule` that you will use to call `forRoot` or `forChild`. When you import the route, this will be imported automatically.

So, you will get the RouterLink either this way, or via direct import into `imports` property of `@NgModule`.

Comment: I have the imported the RouterModule into my main AppModule, then i imported some of my child Modules into my main AppModule as well.  I thought that since i imported RouterModule at my AppModule level it would be usable everywhere.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @cobolstinks no, `declarations` are not inherited, this includes components, directives, and pipes. If you need to use any of these in a module, then you need to import the containing module into that module. That's just how it is.

Comment: Ok thanks, It turns out i needed to define my module routes in their own routing configuration file and import that into each of the modules.  It seems to work now.  Thanks for sending me down the correct path.

Comment: @cobolstinks you are welcome. :-)

Comment: Hi @cobolstinks, i'm having the same issue, can you elaborate on how you fixed it?

Comment: @Kimmiekim have a look at this link on angular.io https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I've been finding this error 1.000 times without the right solution. If you're using webpack. Angular breaks with this error in default production! This is due to the html-minifier in the html-loader, causing attributes to be cast to lowercase!

add caseSensitive: true to the html-loader options

see: github.com/SamanthaAdrichem/webpack-3.9.1-splitted-config-angular

for a working angular 5 + webpack 3.9 config

Answer (score 3):

Some of the syntax has changed since rc-4, especially if you were not using router 3.0.

Follow the RouterLink Section here.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Few other things to check is the `Configuration` part that sets up the  app.module.ts.

Hopefully this sets you in the right direction!