# How to solve error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-router

I work on angular 11 I face error when build angular app

```
    ERROR in src/app/Employee-list/employee-list.component.html:22:45 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 
'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
<a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="['/employee-list']">Staff List</a>
```

and below is package json file

```
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.0"
```

on application module I do as below :

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
 
  imports: [
    RouterModule
```

so How to solve issue ?

sample of app modules and component employee list exist as blow

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uffug5?file=src%2Fapp%2FEmployee-list%2Femployee-list.component.ts
```

image for issue

[image: issue router link]

Comment: This is a pretty common issue, do any of the answers in the following threads help you? [Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property](/questions/42035387/cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-property), [Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734632/cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-a), [Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'](/questions/41268477/template-parse-errors-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-propert)

Comment: thank you for reply i already add RouterModule on import section of app module so please can you help me i try more for this issue

Comment: Can you please post your entire app.module as well as your employeeList HTML file and employeeList component file?

Comment: this is entirly app.module and employeecomponent https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uffug5?file=src%2Fapp%2FEmployee-list%2Femployee-list.component.ts

Comment: i post it entirly app.module and component employeelist are you goted

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: can any one help me i really search more on internet for solve to this issue

Comment: i spent more time to solve issue can any one help me tell me what i do are this issue from angular version or  what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to change `[routerLink]="['/employee-list']"` to `routerLink="/employee-list"`

or you have to set a property in your component like this and change routerlink:

```
export class yourComponent {

    public yourRouterLink= "/employee-list"; // Here is your employee-list
}
```

---

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="yourRouterLink">Staff List</a>
```